# Composite primary key Vs Normal single primary key in cassandra

Tags: solr, cassandra, hive, datastax-enterprise, datastax

I am using DSE4.5 and i have a cassandra table with 5 compound primary key (row key) and 10 more columns.
And for read i m using solr and hive.

If i create same table with rowkey of single column with combination of  all five compound keys and use it as primary key then i observe  read(from solr and hive) and also write(on cassandra) performance will increase cos for read i am creating indexes by solr on each column .

As i inserted 10million record by copy command in compound primary key table it tooks 20 min
where as with single column row key it tooks 4 mins.(**is this time difference is due to clustering keys**)?
Ans also in read from hive there is big difference in response time.

====================================================================================
My current table structure is like: Compound primary key(year,quater,month,userid,datetime) and 10 other columns.My read query will  filter on userid and datetime or by year and userid (actually its not fixed) by solr and hive.                                            So in this case partition column is year and other approach i concatenate all 5 columns and make it single primary key in separate column.By doing this i am getting good insertion performance and also good read from solr and hive.

By doing this partition is done for each row.

Now my question is : Is this is a good practice?

As my read request is not fixed ,it might be start filtering from parition key or may be not.
  1. Does these partitioning of data in cassandra tables impacts solr indexs or if i use single (concatenation of 5 columns) column and create indexs by solr is better for me?

2. If i have billions of rows in table then partition is done on the behalf of each row(as partition key is unique) then does it create any problem?

And if we talk about only insertion ,is there any difference in performance between these two approaches (compound key and single column primary key)?

Number of nodes 5 with two datacenter 
1, DC 1 solr ,1cassandra
2, DC 1 solr,1cassandra,1 hadoop

RF-3

Please suggest..
Thanks

Comment: Please clarify with an actual table definition since you are not quite using the standard terminology. For example, what exactly is the "partition key" and which columns are part of the partition key ("composite partition key") vs. columns that are "clustering columns" that constitute a "compound primary key". I mean, some people still use the old terminology of "row key" for what is now referred to as the "partition key", while some people use "row key" to mean what is now more properly called the "primary key" in CQL3. Thanks!

Comment: Generally, it is more a matter of how you you will be querying your data. IOW, to what extent you wish to do non-Solr CQL queries that require rows to be "clustered" into the same partition, such as to be on the same node for performance.

Comment: Also, what is you cluster configuration - number of nodes and RF?

Comment: Hi Jack ,thanks for review ,i have edited my question .Please have a look.Thanks